# Getting error while adding a trusted site

Tags: community, security, community-builder, csp

I am adding some markup in "Head Markup" section of Community Builder(Settings --> Advanced) that references resources from 3rd party websites. Thus, SFDC gives me CSP violation warning in the markup. To resolve this I went to Settings --> Security --> Content Security Policy (CSP) and changed policy to:

**Allow Inline Scripts and Script Access to White listed Third-party Hosts**

And went on to add these sites in **trusted sites**. Then I whitelisted them in**CSP Errors** section.

However, there is  this one site that is giving me error as shown below:

[image]

This site is coming in **"CSP Error"** section:

[image]

But when I click on whitelist button, nothing happens, the page refreshes and I get errors as:

[image]

I have also added these sites in Trusted sites in Salesforce org --> Settings -->  Security Controls --> CSP Trusted Sites. But it is not working.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

at the moment there isn't any fix. You can find updates here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001FSlqQAG

BR,
Simone.

Comment: This article talks about error that comes when we are using a lightning:map. Here I am not using one.

Comment: Hi @Sarang try to add only domain instead of whole url (as follow without spaces) -->

https:// www. googletagmanager. com

Comment: I did that but to no avail.